# What is the difference between these two implementations?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm just learning java and have come across two ways to do the same thing. My question is: what is the difference between them? Thanks.

Option A:

```
class Foo {
    public static int var;

    Foo (){
        var = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo object = new Foo();
        object.method();
        System.out.println(object.var); //prints 1
    }

    public void method (){
        var++;
    }
}
```

Option B:

```
class Foo {
    public static int var;

    Foo (){
        var = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo object = new Foo();
        method(object);
        System.out.println(object.var); //prints 1
    }

    public static void method (Foo object){
        object.var++;
    }
}
```

Comment: A is incrementing the `var` using an object's method the B is increment `var` using a static method that can be called without creating an object.

Comment: Why pass Foo object in Option B when it's not used?

Comment: No difference, other than code style / clarity

Comment: @Samuari I meant to do object.var++. This does bring up another question though, if I modify an instance variables it changes its value for all objects?

Comment: you should never use a static field in a instance context, so both options should create compiler warnings when you use `foo.var` as it is a clear sign for wrong usage. Assigning a static variable in an constructor is also highly dubious. I suspect you dont want to make var static, otherwise the code is pretty pointless. In all places `Foo.var++;` can be used (which makes it clear the object is not used in B).

Comment: maybe it's not late to read [why-are-static-variables-considered-evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Answer (score 0):

To reinforce what @eckes mentioned above -

There's more common in those samples than different - both are obscure and promote bad practice
[Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> Note: You can also refer to static fields with an object reference
> like
>
> myBike.numberOfBicycles
>
> but this is **discouraged** because it does not make it clear that they are class variables.

Clean way to increment a static variable in this case: `Foo.var++`
And in a real life example it's usually wrong to have mutable static variables. Especially if your're a beginner.